Consequence of Ambrosetti-Rabinowitz type inequality
I want to get an inequality which is a consequence of an Ambrosetti-Rabinowitz type inequality, namely:
Suppose that $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous odd function such that
$\begin{align}
\alpha G(s) \leq g(s)s \leq \beta G(s), \text{ for all }s \in \mathbb{R},
\end{align}$
where $0< \alpha \leq \beta$ are real constants and $G(s) = \int_0^sg(t) \hspace{0.1cm} dt$.
My goal is to show that for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$\begin{cases}
s^\beta G(t) \leq G(ts) \leq s^\alpha G(t), \text{ if }\ s\leq 1,\\
s^\alpha G(t) \leq G(ts) \leq s^\beta G(t), \text{ if } s \geq 1.
\end{cases}$$
My doubt arose when I started studying the article, page 1636. I think this must follow from some manipulation involving the logarithm function, but I don't know how to do this.

I recall the context, adding one little (relevant) assumption about $g$ (in italic).
Context: Let $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous odd function such that
$$ (\ast) \qquad \alpha G(s) \le g(s) s \le \beta G(s)$$
where $0 < \alpha \le \beta$ and $G(s) = \int_0^s g(u) du$. Moreover, if $g$ is not identically $0$, we assume $g$ vanishes only at $0$ in a neighborhood of $0$.
Claim: For all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and all $s \ge 0$,
\begin{align}
(\ast\ast) \qquad \begin{cases}
(a) \quad s^{\beta} G(t) \le G(ts) \le s^{\alpha} G(t) \; \mbox{ if $s \le 1$},\\
(b) \quad s^{\alpha} G(t) \le G(ts) \le s^{\beta} G(t) \; \mbox{ if $s \ge 1$}.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Remark: The assumption I added on $g$ is relevant. The claim is clear if $g$ is identically $0$, so assume $g$ is not constant. We shall see that, from $(\ast)$, $g$ and $G$ always have the same sign and hence $G$ is monotonic on $[0, +\infty)$. Hence there is some $t_0 > 0$ such that $G(t) \neq 0$ for every $t > t_0$. Suppose (against the additionnal assumption) that $g$ does vanish for some $t'_0 < t_0$ and pick $0 < s_0 < 1$ such that $t'_0 = s_0 t_0$. Then $(\ast \ast a)$ cannot hold for $t = t_0$ and $s = s_0$, since $G(t'_0) = 0$ too.
Proof of claim: The claim is clear if $g$ is the zero function, hence assume that $g$ is not constant. Clearly, $g(0) = G(0) = 0$, and $G$ is even since $g$ is odd. From $(\ast)$, we see that for all $s \ge 0$, $g(s)$ and $G(s)$ have the same sign; since $g$ is continuous, this implies that $g$ and $G$ never vanish 'once they stopped vanishing' (i.e. $g$ and $G$ can only vanish on an interval centred on $0$) and that $G$ is monotonic on $[0, +\infty)$. From the assumption that $g \neq 0$ over $(0, \delta)$ for some $\delta > 0$, we deduce  that $g, G \neq 0$ over $(0, + \infty)$.
The claim is clear for $t = 0$. Since $G$ is even, it suffices to consider $t > 0$. The claim is also clear for $s=0$. We note that $(\ast \ast a)$ (with $s > 0$) follows from $(\ast \ast b)$ by change of variables $s' = 1/s$ and $t' = ts$. Hence it suffices to prove
$$ (\ast \ast ') \qquad  \quad s^{\alpha} G(t) \le G(ts) \le s^{\beta} G(t) \; \mbox{ for all $t > 0$ and $s \ge  1$.}$$
Fix some arbitrary $t > 0$, and set $f(s) = G(ts)/G(t)$ for $s \ge 0$. (This is well-defined.) Note that $f(1) = 1$. This function is differentiable:
$$ f'(s) = t G'(ts)/G(t) = t g(ts)/G(t) . $$
From this and $(\ast)$, we get for $s \ge 1$:
$$ \alpha f(s)/s = \alpha G(ts)/sG(t) \le ts g(ts)/sG(t) = f'(s) \le \beta f(s)/s ,  $$
i.e.,
$$ \alpha/s \le f'(s)/f(s) \le \beta/s \, .$$
Integrating between $1$ and $s$ ($1 \le s$) and recalling $f(1) = 1$, we get:
$$ ln(s^{\alpha}) \le ln(f(s)) \le ln(s^{\beta}), $$
i.e., taking exponentials,
$$ s^{\alpha} \le f(s) \le s^{\beta}.$$
Multiplying everywhere by $G(t)$ yields $(\ast \ast ')$. QED
